# wget using an environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I need to do a wget of a file url concatenated with a variable known as Initial

but if i do for instance,

```
Initial="something"

wget www.google.ca/${Initial}
```

output:

```
www.google.ca/$%7BInitial%7D
```

I want to get desired output of:

```
www.google.ca/something
```

thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior at all.  Works fine here.  Can you paste a [small test case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: are you using single quotes when calling wget?

Comment: What shell are you using? bash? Please post the complete console output when running these commands.

Comment: As @perreal suggested, you're probably using single quotes like `wget 'www.g.c/${Initial}'`. Remove the quotes or replace with `"` and you're good.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the code you pasted and it works:

```
Initial="something"
wget www.google.com/${Initial}
```

and the output is:

```
www.google.com/something
```

You can also try using:

```
Initial="something"
GoogleLink="www.google.com/"$Initial
wget $GoogleLink
```

and the output is the same.

If you have copied/pasted the script code, some additional characters may have been added. It depends on the editor you use. I suggest that you re-write the script in a new and clean file.

**EDIT**:
After [tvm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454443/tvm)'s suggestion, in order to avoid whitespace problems, try:

```
wget "$GoogleLink"
```

Comment: Above should work. I would recommend using wget "$GoogleLink" though, to avoid whitespace problems.